# Issue with collision model in Gazebo

Tags: gazebo, rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm seeing two different but similar issues with the collision model in Gazebo and I wanted to make sure I'm using it right. In both cases, the collision model looks right in RVIZ but not in Gazebo.

The first case is with the new Gazebo plugin model. I set initial positions for the joints using the SetJointPosition function in Model.hh and then turn on the collision model in Gazebo and it appears as if only the visual model was moved by the function.

The second case is the NASA R2 simulator (http://ros.org/wiki/nasa_r2_simulator). The controller is derived from pr2_controller_interface::Controller. In this case, no initial position is set but 0 is outside of the joint limits for some of the joints so Gazebo immediately pushes the joints into their limits. The controller then grabs the current position and sets that as the goal. Again, looking at the collision model in Gazebo shows that it is not aligned with the visual model. You can try this one out to see what I'm talking about.

Is there some kind of update call that is needed for Gazebo to handle these things properly or is this a bug in Gazebo?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38774/issue-with-collision-model-in-gazebo/) by [rctaylor](https://answers.ros.org/users/2644/rctaylor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2012-07-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rctaylor](https://answers.ros.org/users/2644/rctaylor/) on 2012-07-17**:
I've noticed that the problem is inconsistent which leads me to believe it has something to do with the order (or timing) of things being loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This likely is the same issue reported [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/32849/visual-and-collision-geometry-misaligned-in-gazebo/). I created a ticket on the gazebo trac [here](https://kforge.ros.org/gazebo/trac/ticket/59) and a bug was found in the way transformations are aggregated. The fix doesn't seem to have been incorporated yet however.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-07-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rctaylor](https://answers.ros.org/users/2644/rctaylor/) on 2012-07-16**:
It sounds like you have a fixed version of Gazebo. Could you try the NASA R2 simulator to confirm that the fix resolves this problem as well? Should just require 2 steps (sudo apt-get install nasa_r2_simulator; roslaunch r2_gazebo r2_empty.launch). The problem is obvious in the elbow and fingers.